# How to stop nextjs from making server call for route with parameter in it?

Tags: next.js, dynamic-pages

Scenario:
I have one url like this one `/posts/:id/edit`
Using standard nextjs structure, file lies at
`posts -> [id] -> edit.tsx`

Inside this url, from the id we make AJAX call from react to get the post and show an edit form to the user.

We want to avoid the hassle of nextjs calling the server every time and running getStaticProps and getStaticPaths for every id.

It is enough to reuse getStaticProps for all different ids,

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }: GetStaticPropsContext): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<SSRConfig>> {
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale || DEFAULT_LOCALE, tNamespaces)),
        },
    };
}
```

and we don't need get `getStaticPaths` method at all, but next forces to use it.

Right now next generates under .next/static/pages one html,json pair for every possible id resulting in a lot of useless data.

All the different post ids have same props, basically for this particular page we want to return regardless of ids same js and html back, and stop next from creating so much pages and running getStaticPaths.

We cannot keep the page without the method, otherwise next build or start does not work.

Any idea how to optimise this use case ? We have a lot of such scenarios, also with email confirmation tokens etc where under .next/static/pages are generated hundred thousands of useless htmls for every id. We have cron jobs now deleting those but is not a proper solution

Comment: If you're statically generating a dynamic route then `getStaticPaths` has to be used. Have you considered not using a dynamic route for those pages, and pass the id as a query param to fetch the data on the client-side? Or, you could use SSR instead with `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: That is not a solution, I want clean and nice urls like that, instead of using query params. PS: transferring site from vue to nextjs, lot of blockers to achieve fantastic performance. Many things that next does not support and I will write a post about. I hoped that was possible to allow some cases to be handled only in client like this one checked online cannot find such a solution. Not all routes need to generate static props based on different path combos

Comment: If you really need to stick with statically generated dynamic routes, there's another option of using [`fallback: 'blocking'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking) in `getStaticPaths`, and return an empty array in `paths`. This would mean the pages would be generated when they're requested, rather than generating everything at build time.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that and using that already. I return [] paths as tokens are generated at runtime. My issue is something else, I want to return same html/js/props for all possible url parameters path, or EVEN better what i was doing in vue, handle a particular url in client react router only (so far form my reasearch nextjs does not support this, a mix of ssr and client only routes)

Comment: I handle all logic for some urls like /user/activate/:token in client side only, no need to ssr there. React component gets token from path, then makes some api call to confirm email. Here I dont want next to generate in .next/static/pages hundred thousand /user/active/334.html/json/js and so on for all tokens. I just want to avoid sending backend request at all for some urls and handle in client react router, OR alternatively force next to return same props for all url param combos (in case of server returned translations for ex)

Comment: I understand, but in that case you can't use dynamic routes as they'll required you to either use `getStaticPaths` or use SSR with `getServerSideProps`. As I said, you can pass the id/token as a query param, and still keep the URL as you want. You can use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) and map something like `/user/activate/334` to `/user/active?token=334`.

Comment: Thanks, last sentence is pointing me to something of a practical solution. I will try the rewrites, I want to keep for the user/browser history and consistency with old webs the url parameters as they have monitoring meaning as well in system. Hopefully rewrites achieve this in theory should be possible will try that out